# cas redis ticket registry

Tags: redis, cas, high-availability

I want to implement HA/Clustering for Apereo CAS using Redis as Ticket Storage. I deployed all components on one local machine, so I'd got setup:

> - cas server (version 5.3.1) on tomcat (version 9.0.8)
> - redis (version 3.0.501) quorum of 3 instances on local machine

I receive exception while tryng store TGT into redis -

> ***JedisDataException: ERR invalid expire time in setex***

Does any one know, what am I missing here?

Whats wrong in my cas.properties?

***cas Redis properties:***

```
# Redis Ticket Registry
cas.ticket.registry.redis.host=localhost
cas.ticket.registry.redis.port=6380
cas.ticket.registry.redis.database=1
cas.ticket.registry.redis.password=
cas.ticket.registry.redis.timeout=2000
cas.ticket.registry.redis.useSsl=false
cas.ticket.registry.redis.usePool=true
# 
cas.ticket.registry.redis.pool.max-active=20
cas.ticket.registry.redis.pool.maxIdle=8
cas.ticket.registry.redis.pool.minIdle=0
cas.ticket.registry.redis.pool.maxActive=8
cas.ticket.registry.redis.pool.maxWait=-1
cas.ticket.registry.redis.pool.numTestsPerEvictionRun=0
cas.ticket.registry.redis.pool.softMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis=0
cas.ticket.registry.redis.pool.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=0
cas.ticket.registry.redis.pool.lifo=true
cas.ticket.registry.redis.pool.fairness=false
# 
cas.ticket.registry.redis.pool.testOnCreate=false
cas.ticket.registry.redis.pool.testOnBorrow=false
cas.ticket.registry.redis.pool.testOnReturn=false
cas.ticket.registry.redis.pool.testWhileIdle=false
# 
cas.ticket.registry.redis.sentinel.master=mymaster
cas.ticket.registry.redis.sentinel.node[0]=localhost:26380
cas.ticket.registry.redis.sentinel.node[1]=localhost:26381
cas.ticket.registry.redis.sentinel.node[2]=localhost:26382
```

***Exception:***

```
2018-07-13 18:38:36,763 ERROR [org.apereo.cas.ticket.registry.RedisTicketRegistry] - <Failed to add [TGT-1-********************************************************mjz04b-vHVkgb0-dar-1-29626]>
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: ERR invalid expire time in setex; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: ERR invalid expire time in setex
        at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisExceptionConverter.convert(JedisExceptionConverter.java:64) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.13.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisExceptionConverter.convert(JedisExceptionConverter.java:41) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.13.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.data.redis.PassThroughExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(PassThroughExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:37) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.13.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.data.redis.FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:37) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.13.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.convertJedisAccessException(JedisConnection.java:241) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.13.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.setEx(JedisConnection.java:1407) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.13.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultValueOperations$11.potentiallyUsePsetEx(DefaultValueOperations.java:193) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.13.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultValueOperations$11.doInRedis(DefaultValueOperations.java:186) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.13.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:207) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.13.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:169) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.13.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.execute(AbstractOperations.java:91) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.13.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultValueOperations.set(DefaultValueOperations.java:182) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.13.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultBoundValueOperations.set(DefaultBoundValueOperations.java:65) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.13.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at org.apereo.cas.ticket.registry.RedisTicketRegistry.addTicket(RedisTicketRegistry.java:57) ~[cas-server-support-redis-ticket-registry-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
        at org.apereo.cas.DefaultCentralAuthenticationService.createTicketGrantingTicket(DefaultCentralAuthenticationService.java:393) ~[cas-server-core-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
        at org.apereo.cas.DefaultCentralAuthenticationService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$b02e48f2.invoke(<generated>) ~[cas-server-core-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:736) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:84) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.apereo.inspektr.audit.AuditTrailManagementAspect.handleAuditTrail(AuditTrailManagementAspect.java:135) ~[inspektr-audit-1.8.3.GA.jar:1.8.3.GA]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor246.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:627) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:616) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:168) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.MeteredMethodInterceptor.invoke(MeteredMethodInterceptor.java:45) ~[metrics-spring-3.1.3.jar:?]
        at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.MeteredMethodInterceptor.invoke(MeteredMethodInterceptor.java:32) ~[metrics-spring-3.1.3.jar:?]
        at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.AbstractMetricMethodInterceptor.invoke(AbstractMetricMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[metrics-spring-3.1.3.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.TimedMethodInterceptor.invoke(TimedMethodInterceptor.java:48) ~[metrics-spring-3.1.3.jar:?]
        at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.TimedMethodInterceptor.invoke(TimedMethodInterceptor.java:34) ~[metrics-spring-3.1.3.jar:?]
        at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.AbstractMetricMethodInterceptor.invoke(AbstractMetricMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[metrics-spring-3.1.3.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.CountedMethodInterceptor.invoke(CountedMethodInterceptor.java:46) ~[metrics-spring-3.1.3.jar:?]
        at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.CountedMethodInterceptor.invoke(CountedMethodInterceptor.java:32) ~[metrics-spring-3.1.3.jar:?]
        at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.AbstractMetricMethodInterceptor.invoke(AbstractMetricMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[metrics-spring-3.1.3.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:671) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.apereo.cas.DefaultCentralAuthenticationService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1eac4046.createTicketGrantingTicket(<generated>) ~[cas-server-core-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
        at org.apereo.cas.web.flow.login.CreateTicketGrantingTicketAction.createOrUpdateTicketGrantingTicket(CreateTicketGrantingTicketAction.java:95) ~[cas-server-support-actions-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
        at org.apereo.cas.web.flow.login.CreateTicketGrantingTicketAction.doExecute(CreateTicketGrantingTicketAction.java:59) ~[cas-server-support-actions-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
        at org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor259.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:216) ~[spring-core-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$LockedScopedProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GenericScope.java:470) ~[spring-cloud-context-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy193.execute(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.webflow.action.EvaluateAction.doExecute(EvaluateAction.java:77) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionState.doEnter(ActionState.java:101) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:228) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.execute(FlowExecutionImpl.java:395) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.execute(RequestControlContextImpl.java:214) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.TransitionableState.handleEvent(TransitionableState.java:116) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.handleEvent(Flow.java:547) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.handleEvent(FlowExecutionImpl.java:390) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.handleEvent(RequestControlContextImpl.java:210) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionState.doEnter(ActionState.java:105) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:228) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.execute(FlowExecutionImpl.java:395) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.execute(RequestControlContextImpl.java:214) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.TransitionableState.handleEvent(TransitionableState.java:116) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.handleEvent(Flow.java:547) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.handleEvent(FlowExecutionImpl.java:390) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.handleEvent(RequestControlContextImpl.java:210) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.handleEvent(ViewState.java:231) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:195) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:537) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:259) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:168) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:216) ~[spring-core-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$LockedScopedProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GenericScope.java:470) ~[spring-cloud-context-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy191.resumeExecution(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:254) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[servlet-api.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[servlet-api.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-websocket.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.apereo.cas.web.support.AuthenticationCredentialsThreadLocalBinderClearingFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationCredentialsThreadLocalBinderClearingFilter.java:30) ~[cas-server-core-web-api-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.apereo.cas.security.RequestParameterPolicyEnforcementFilter.doFilter(RequestParameterPolicyEnforcementFilter.java:261) ~[cas-server-security-filter-2.0.10.2.jar:2.0.10.2]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.apereo.cas.security.ResponseHeadersEnforcementFilter.doFilter(ResponseHeadersEnforcementFilter.java:237) ~[cas-server-security-filter-2.0.10.2.jar:2.0.10.2]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.apereo.cas.security.AddResponseHeadersFilter.doFilter(AddResponseHeadersFilter.java:94) ~[cas-server-security-filter-2.0.10.2.jar:2.0.10.2]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:111) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar:1.5.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.apereo.cas.logging.web.ThreadContextMDCServletFilter.doFilter(ThreadContextMDCServletFilter.java:91) ~[cas-server-core-logging-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar:1.5.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:130) ~[spring-boot-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar:1.5.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:66) ~[spring-boot-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar:1.5.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:105) ~[spring-boot-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar:1.5.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:123) ~[spring-boot-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar:1.5.14.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.apereo.inspektr.common.web.ClientInfoThreadLocalFilter.doFilter(ClientInfoThreadLocalFilter.java:66) ~[inspektr-common-1.8.3.GA.jar:1.8.3.GA]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71) ~[log4j-web-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:412) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1385) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.8]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-util.jar:9.0.8]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_172]
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: ERR invalid expire time in setex
        at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.processError(Protocol.java:127) ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar:?]
        at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:161) ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar:?]
        at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:215) ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar:?]
        at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.readProtocolWithCheckingBroken(Connection.java:340) ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar:?]
        at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getStatusCodeReply(Connection.java:239) ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar:?]
        at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.setex(BinaryJedis.java:616) ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.setEx(JedisConnection.java:1405) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.13.RELEASE.jar:?]
        ... 171 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've only just encountered this issue myself.
It's not a problem with the Redis configuration.
The issue is with the expiry policy for the TGT.
If you are using the timeout expiration policy you will have this key set (to some value in seconds):

```
cas.ticket.tgt.timeout.maxTimeToLiveInSeconds=
```

I believe there is a problem in the 5.3.x code that means it ends up trying to cast Long.MAX_VALUE to an integer, resulting in a value of -1.
So the TimeoutExpirationPolicy class uses this as a baked in value:

```
public Long getTimeToLive() {
    return Long.MAX_VALUE;
}
```

The RedisTicketRegistry class does this:

```
private static int getTimeout(final Ticket ticket) {
    final int ttl = ticket.getExpirationPolicy().getTimeToLive().intValue();
    if (ttl == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    return ttl;
}
```

And that value is eventually passed through the Redis client code and ends up using a -1 value for the seconds in the Redis SETEX command.

It looks to be fixed in the latest CAS code (V6).
Though to workaround this I altered the expiration policy to use the Default policy, thus setting the likes of these 2 properties instead (Make sure the above one is NOT set):

```
cas.ticket.tgt.maxTimeToLiveInSeconds=7200
cas.ticket.tgt.timeToKillInSeconds=7200
```

This then meant that the Redis server application was sent the value 7200 with the SETEX command.